# Select only the first two digits of a string of the value that starts with a letter and do nothing otherwise

Tags: r

how can I select only the first two digits of a string of the value that starts with a letter and do nothing otherwise?

```
Value = I240 G460 1560 S50
```

I would like to get:

```
Value = I24 G46 1560 S50
```

So far I am trying:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Value = ifelse(str_detect(Value, '[A-Z]'~'\\d{2}')))
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work - is ``Value`` meant to be a vector or a string. either way, it needs some quotes somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack solution - there is likely a better way:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Value = c("I240", "G460", "1560", "S50"))

df %>% 
  mutate(temp = substr(Value,1,1),
         temp = is.na(as.numeric(as.character(temp))),
         Value = ifelse(temp == TRUE, substr(Value,1,3), Value)) %>% 
  select(-temp)
```

This gives us:

```
 Value
1   I24
2   G46
3  1560
4   S50
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

Value = c("I240", "G460", "1560", "S50")

df <- data.frame(Value = Value)

df %>% 
  mutate(out = ifelse(str_detect(Value, "^[A-Z]"), str_sub(Value, 1, 3), Value))
#>   Value  out
#> 1  I240  I24
#> 2  G460  G46
#> 3  1560 1560
#> 4   S50  S50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

base

```r
df$out <- with(df, ifelse(grepl("^[A-Z]", Value), substring(Value, 1, 3), Value))
df
#>   Value  out
#> 1  I240  I24
#> 2  G460  G46
#> 3  1560 1560
#> 4   S50  S50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` solution is this:

```
sub("^([A-Z]\\d\\d).*", "\\1", df$Value)
[1] "I24"  "G46"  "1560" "S50"
```

Here, we pick out the initial letter and the two digits following it in a capture group, which we select through backreference `\\1` in the replacement argument to `sub`.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Value = c("I240", "G460", "1560", "S50"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `coalesce` with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Value = coalesce(str_extract(Value, "^[A-Z]\\d{2}"), Value))
```

---

Or using `str_remove` with a regex lookaround

```
df %>%
     mutate(Value = str_remove(Value, "(?<=^[A-Z]\\d{2}).*"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Value = c("I240", "G460", "1560", "S50")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `gsub`

```
> gsub("(^[[:alpha:]]\\d{2}).*","\\1",v)
[1] "I24"  "G46"  "1560" "S50"
```

**data**

```
v <- c("I240", "G460", "1560", "S50")
```